# Importing file into iPad app (Phonegap) -- works ONLY if the app is already running...can I fix?

Tags: xcode, cordova

So Im opening a file into my program and things work just fine as long as the app has already been launched.

If its not, it doesnt pick up my PHONEGAP js function handleOpenURL() ...am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Phonegap is really smart!!!  In this instance, Phonegap sends us an invokeString variable... so onDeviceReady, you just check it here and send it to your import method!

```
if (invokeString) {
        handleOpenURL(invokeString);
    }
```